# How to find such a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-functions

> Let $D$ be the first open quadrant ($x,y>0$). Find an elementary
> function that maps $D$ **onto** the interior of the complement
> $int(\mathbb{C}-D)$.

Edit: I thought of using De-Moivre's formula, $(\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2) ) ^3 =\cos(3\pi/2)+i\sin(3\pi/2) $. So, the function I am looking for will most likely be something involving $z^3$. But, how can I then "rotate" the complex numbers so that the resulting map will be onto the interior of the complement?

Thank you

Comment: *Hints:* $D$ is delimited by two rays meeting at which angle? And what about the complement? Do you know an elementary function which multiplies the arguments by a constant factor?

Comment: Thank you Martin. I am now editing my question

Comment: You are very close now. “Rotation” in the complex plane is multiplication with some constant factor ...

Comment: So I guess I should choose $z^3 \cdot e^{i \pi/2}$? Thank you!!!

Comment: @Dr.John Yes, but it looks lazy not to simplify $e^{i\pi/2}$ to $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. $D$ is the set of all complex numbers with an argument in the range $(0, \pi/2)$. The function $z \mapsto z^3$ maps that to the set $\{ 0 < \arg(z) < 3\pi/2)$.

This can be mapped onto the target domain $int(\Bbb C \setminus D) = \{ \pi/2 < \arg(z) < 2\pi$ with a multiplication with a complex number having the argument $\pi/2$.

So one possible choice for the desired function is $f(z) = iz^3$.

Comment: Thank you Marin R!!!!